# Stack manipulation in C without using inline assembly

Tags: c

I've been preparing for a coding contest, and came across this question on the Internet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void a(); 
void b(); 
void c();

int main() { a(); printf("\n"); return 0; }

void a() { b(); printf("hi "); }

void b() { c(); printf("there "); }

void c()
{
    int x;
    // code here and nowhere else
}
```

The solution is to write code that would print out "hi there" instead of "there hi" (no additional printing functions may be used and code only goes in the comment block).

Since I've done some basic assembly coding, I realized that this could be done with stack manipulation using the integer `x` as the base.

I tried using gdb to find the return address of the functions and then swapped the return addresses of `a` and `b`. The compiler throws a segmentation fault, and thus I assume that I haven't used the proper return address.

How do I properly calculate the offset to find the return address? Info frame command on gdb wasn't helpful, as using the stack address value given there didn't work.

I'm running this on Linux using gcc.

Comment: There is no requirement in C++ to use a stack for local variable storage.  Any stack manipulation tricks would be *undefined behavior*.

Comment: BTW, this looks like C because you are using `#include <stdio.h>` instead of `#include <cstdio>` for C++.  So, which language are you referring to?  C and C++ are different langauges.

Comment: There is no requirement that the local variable `x` to have a memory address.  The compiler is free to encode the variable in a register.

Comment: The *return address* of a called function can be changed by changing the order of the function calls.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks for making SO an overall good experience in the comments sections.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews -- this is obviously a question from some hackaton. There really is no need to spam comments about how to make the code valid, it's not really the point here. "Cleverness" is the point. Hence the challenge.

Comment: What's amusing is that this question is well related to "StackOverflow".

Comment: I closed the problem.  it depends on the implementation of the C compiler and it's not about C.

Comment: Can you use C++ instead of C?  It makes a large difference here. gcc *can* compile C++ code, so it's not that clear from the question.

Comment: Are you allowed to add the line static int called = 0?

Comment: Is the program allowed to print more text after it prints the initial `"hi there\n"`? Please update the question with the exact requirement of the problem.

Comment: you need clearly state that `a`, `b` and `c` - really the functions, that compiler not inline it. by add some attribute (for `CL` this is `__declspec(noinline)` ) - with this and only with this solution is exist

Comment: Can you disclose what contest are you preparing for and where did you took the code from ?

Comment: and here sense in exactly `printf` result swap, or `printf` here only for visual effect, but really task more general - `void a() { b(); somefunc("hi "); }` `void b() { c(); somefunc("there "); }` - and swap calls order to `somefunc` where `somefunc` can be any, not exactly `printf` but say modal dialog show with input string

Comment: It's not about hacking the stack or any other hardware, OS or compiler-dependent feature. But the correct answer depends on the exact text of the question.

Comment: @axiac - question not exact - are `a` `b` and `c` can be inlined ? OP not say this exactly. are important that `printf` called in `a` or `b` or we can generalize question and replace `printf` to another `somefunc` about which `c` have no any knowledge ?

Comment: @RbMm everybody focused on hacking the stack, return addresses etc. My feeling is that the problem is about the algorithm and the answer doesn't require any special coding or hacking technique (and it should work the same using any language). However, until the OP puts the original text of the problem, we can only speculate.

Comment: @axiac - yes. let wait for OP - for he clarity self question - task in stack hack or `printf` hack

Comment: @axiac I agree with you. My instincts is that the original questions (not necessary what OP is asking)  is about using recursion to obtain the effect which shall workout with any language support recursion and persistent state. However I fail to find a solution without at least use some Unix specific feature

Comment: I am still not sure if C++ is allowed.  The question originally had a C++ tag.  It was removed and it now appears to have only C tag.  But it uses C++ style comments.  There are stack manipulation mechanisms in C++ which do not exist in C.  So it's essential to know whether C++ features are allowed.  Do you need to code to compile with 'gcc --pedantic --std=c99 filename.c' or are you ok with it compiling with 'gcc --std=c++03 filename.cpp' ?

Comment: You can keep the state between different calls of a free function inside of a local static variable.  As an experiment, you can declare `static void * x_ptr = 0;` after the `// code here ` line.  Then you can check the value of `x_ptr` and call main: `if (!x_ptr) { x_ptr = (void*)&x; (void)main();} else { int diff = (x_ptr - ((void*)&x)) ; printf("%d %lu\n",  diff, sizeof(x)); }`.  This will show you how much all 4 functions (+sizeof(x)) are adding to the stack.  The problem is that the compiler will pad the stack quite a bit.

Comment: (cont.) The values will differ depending on whether you choose to not optimize at all or optimize with -O1, -O2, or -O3.  The main idea of how to gage the stack size will still be based on using the static local variable, but to make it definitive, it will take some work.  You can even add more `int`s to the stack and keep track of their addresses in separate local static pointers.  You'll see jumps in how much stack is used, but not with every `int` added.  With every few of them.  But since you can keep the state, you can try a lot of options before making a decision on where the values lie.

Comment: May I ask a question, is the title "Stack manipulation in C without using inline assembly" one of the condition of the contest?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if the following will count. It's portable on POSIX. Basically you change the buffer of printf before its first call and manipulate that before before it's flushed to terminal

```
void c()
{
    static int first = 1;

    if (first) {
        first = 0;
        char buf0[BUFSIZ];
        char buf1[BUFSIZ];
        setvbuf(stdout, buf0, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ);
        a();
        memcpy(buf1, buf0 + 6, 3);
        memcpy(buf1 + 3, buf0, 6);
        memcpy(buf0, buf1, 9);
        buf0[8] = '\n';
        fflush(stdout);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

You will get warnings on implicitly declaring library functions `memcpy` and `exit`. It's legal on C89 though discouraged. But in your case, no trick is too dirty, I guess. You can avoid the memcpy by copy the characters manually. You can avoid `exit` by instead redirect `stdout` through `freopen`. You can change `BUFSIZ` to a large constants if the system has a strangely small buffer size (smaller than 9). There are variants of this solution that don't require you to manually insert that `\n` and instead let the program exit normally from main and has the `printf("\n")` to put that end of line

Comment: you solution is based on implementation of `printf` function - that it can be redirected, etc. but it absolute does not correspond to the spirit of the question - how swap return addresses. `printf` here only for visualization result

Comment: @RbMm please read the question more carefully. "Swapping address" is just what the OP thought as the starting point of the solution. My solution only depends on behaviors defined by the POSIX standards

Comment: no - read the question - **"Stack manipulation .."** - so ask the OP - what he really need - reverse functions call or `printf` ? in what **SPIRIT** and **SENSE**

Comment: if code was - `void a() { b(); MessageBox(0, L"hi ", 0, 0); }`  `void b() { c(); MessageBox(0, L"there ", 0, 0); }` - you can reverse this ? but my solution can and do

Answer (score 4):

This problem cannot be solved unless you smash the stack in the same way as an attacker smashes the stack of some process.

And to smesh the stack can be done only if you know each detail of implementation of the compiler, the problem is unsolvable otherwise.

If you know the details of the compilation (the stack structure in particular) you can use the address of the local x variable in order to obtain the addres of the current frame from the stack (of FRAME_C); in each frame is the base pointer of the previous frame and modify it.

The stack looks like that:

```
   FRAME_MAIN = RET_OS   some-data 
   FRAME_A    = RET_MAIN some-data 
   FRAME_B    = RET_A    some-data 
   FRAME_C    = RET_B    some-data(including the variable `x`)
```

Using the `&x` we can detect the position of the FRAME_C.

One solution is

1. to print "Hi" in function c()
2. Modify FRAME_B such that RET_A to become RET_MAIN
3. return from function c() with `return`

The tricky operation is 2. but if each frame has a size that is known, then we can modify the return pointer RET_A of the frame B and detect  RET_MAIN something like that:

```
*(&x+FRAME_C_SIZE+some-small-offset1) =                  /* *&RET_A = */
*(&x+(FRAME_C_SIZE+FRAME_B_SIZE)+some-small-offset2).    /* *&RET_MAIN */
```

As you can see, you need to know a lot of details about the implementation of the compiler , so this is not at all a portable solution.

---

Other solution would be to print "hi, there" and redirect the `stdout` to `/dev/null`.  I suppose that exit() or other compiler-depedent tricks are not allowed, otherwise the problem has no meaning for a contest.

Comment: This problem can be solved, how minimum with `CL` compiler for x86/x64

Comment: no, exist nice and general solution. and not only for `printf` but for any function in place `printf`. and we not need knowledge about frame layout, etc

Answer (score 0):

my solution is for x86/x64 and for `CL` compiler, but think for gcc also exist.

question only - are exist equivalent for function :

[`void ** _AddressOfReturnAddress();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s975zw7k.aspx)

and are equivalent for [`__declspec(noinline)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxybs02x.aspx) - for tell compiler to never inline a particular function

let
`void* pb` - is address in `void b()` just after `c();` 
and
`void* pa` is address in `void a()` just after `b();`

because `a` and `b` almost the same - we can assume that

`(ULONG_PTR)pa - (ULONG_PTR)&a == (ULONG_PTR)pb - (ULONG_PTR)&b;`

and of course stack layout in `a` and `b` must be the same. based on this and solution.
next code tested/worked with `CL` compiler - on both x86/x64 (windows) and with [`/Ox (Full Optimization)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59a3b321.aspx) and with [`/Od (Disable (Debug))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aafb762y.aspx) - all worked.

```
extern "C" void ** _AddressOfReturnAddress();

void a(); 
void b(); 
void c();

int main() { a(); printf("\n"); return 0; }

__declspec(noinline) void a() { b(); printf("hi "); }

__declspec(noinline) void b() { c(); printf("there "); }

__declspec(noinline) void c()
{
    void** pp = _AddressOfReturnAddress();
    void* pb = *pp;
    void* pa = (void*)((ULONG_PTR)&a + ((ULONG_PTR)pb - (ULONG_PTR)&b));
    for (;;)
    {
        if (*++pp == pa)
        {

            *pp = pb;
            *_AddressOfReturnAddress() = pa;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question requires no code outside the comment block in `c`

Comment: @YanZhou - yes, and all my code in `c` - where you view outside code ?!

Comment: You added attributes to a and b and c

Comment: @YanZhou - this is not a code. this tell to compiler not make this functions inline. really OP question implicitly assumes - that this is the functions and exist **return address** . really my solution absolute correct and no any code added outside

Comment: I understand why you need them. But the OP need everything inside C without modifying anything else whatsoever. And technically they are code

Comment: @YanZhou - and this `noinline` need only in case we use optimization (when compiler really remove all this functions call and implement all as plain code). if we not use optimization - we and not need this attribute use

Comment: @YanZhou - no, my solution absolute fit requirements, simply OP not enough correct ask question

Comment: @YanZhou - all question based on **EXIST RETURN ADDRESS**, `a`, `b` and `c` is **FUNCTIONs**
with optimization any compiler simply generate code `printf("there "); printf("hi "); printf("\n");` and task will be have no solution. `__declspec(noinline)` this is not code but **MANDATORY** declaration here that is really function.

Comment: There's no need for stack manipulation or return address. See my answer for a POSIX portable solution to OP's real question. Though it will not work in Windows unless there's a equivalent to `setvbuf`

Comment: @YanZhou - absolute not agree with you and your solution.  it does not correspond to the spirit of the question. task not in `printf` here (it only for visualization)

Comment: The only edits which the question allows are inside the function c(). This answer does not adhere to this requirement at all.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich - I already say - all my code in c() - where you view more code ?! `__declspec(noinline)` you mean ? - this is not a code. this is attribute, which say that function must not be inlined. I let do this because sure that OP simply forget say this by self. or you thing solution can be even in case inlined functions ?

Comment: @RbMm, first of all, you can declare a function inside the definition of `c()`.  But, in this case, it doesn't matter because the intrinsics are part of MSVC.  And `_AddressOfReturnAddress()` is an intrinsic.  And while it is very useful to know, it's part of the language extension.  Essentially, this is as useful as putting an inline-assembly answer when responding to a C question.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich - you yourself something say about "There are stack manipulation" - "calls of a free function" - so you **assume** that this is not inline. but this will be false on optimization, without `__declspec(noinline)` or like this (depended from compiler). you say that we must not declare functions as notinline ? **yes** or **no** ?. you try say that what I write not a solution ? it not work ? (you test?)

Comment: It's C.  There is no inline.  You can ensure it with compiler options `--pedantic --std=c99`.  Even at `-O3` optimization, I see the stack decreasing by 48 bytes with gcc and those options.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich - in C no inline !?! no optimization ?!?

Comment: There is nothing to test if the solution doesn't address the asked question.  You answering *some* question.  Just not the one which the problem asked.  And you are providing some useful information while you do that.  But if the person is asking how to do something with gcc on linux and you provide a solution which only works with a C++ compiler extensions in Windows, the person who asked the question still has the same question they had in the beginning.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich - "solution doesn't address the asked question" - this is only your opinion. I have own - my solution absolute address the question perfect and nice. however nothing to discuss this without OP

Comment: @RbMm.  no, C90 does not have the `inline` keyword.  And even the highest optimization level decreases the stack by 48 bytes.  The only data other than the function frames is the `int`, but adding 2 `int`s makes the stack only 64 bytes.  So the 48 bytes did not come from the 1 `int`.  They came from 4 functions` return addresses being put on the stack.

Comment: re: "this is only your opinion".  What do you mean?  Does the phrase `// code here and nowhere else`  have some room for different interpretations?  Or is using a Windows intrinsic in a question which specifically asks about gcc on linux on topic?

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich - my code and only in c - **where you view another code ?**

Comment: @RbMm, I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "@DmitryRubanovich - my code and only in c - where you view another code ?"  Can you, please, rephrase?

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich - "question which specifically asks about gcc on linux on topic? " - you lie. the OP written that "I'm running this on Linux using gcc." but so what ? question not include requirements - only gcc. Linux or Windows - here at all absolute not related, nothing os specific here

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich - I add code only to `c` func. **where you view another code ?** -

Comment: `extern "C" void ** _AddressOfReturnAddress();` is declared outside the `c()` function.  Which is Ok (it can be moved inside).  But this is still a Windows solution to a linux question.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich - where you view that this is "Linux" question ?! at first OP say nothing about this. at second this is not OS related question. no any different Linux or Windows or iOS. this is can be compiler specific question, but not OS. "_AddressOfReturnAddress(); " this is `CL` specific, but I think that another compilers have equivalent of this function.

Comment: @RbMm, re:"where you view that this is "Linux" question ".  Read the very last line of the question.  re: "at second this is not OS related question".  You are right.  But it is a question about solving a problem using a specific OS environment.  It's not a question about that OS environment.  It's a question about that problem.  But answering it in the context of a different compiler and a different OS is off topic.  Although it is *interesting* because it points out how this problem could be solved in a different setting.  It also shows an interesting MSVS intrinsic.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich - "I'm running this on Linux using gcc." != "must be using gcc and Linux only". OP not clear say about this moment and abandoned from question. this is on hold. so you can have own opinion. I can have self

Comment: @RbMm, this is not an opinion site.  It's a question/answer site.  Saying "must be using gcc and Linux only" would be kind of rude when asking for help.  And asking a question on how to do something is asking for help.  The scope of this question may not be entirely precise, but it is precise enough to know which language and operating system the person is interested in.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich - OP nothing say about are only gcc or any compiler can be used. and this is not practical question. I give the perfect answer. and this worked.